# finding the most puplar artist sql

Tags: php, html, sql, csv

I have a csv file called iTunes.csv with the rows

```
songName,artistName,albumName,ReleasedDate
```

i need to find the artist that have been in most albums. I tried the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT distinct (MAX(A.artistName))
        FROM iTunes A 
        WHERE (SELECT A2.artistName,A2.albumName 
                FROM iTunes A2)";
```

my thinking process is that first if i take just the artistName,albumName rows ill get with no duplicates (seeing in the original you had the same artist in the same album with sevral songs). would love some help

Comment: How are you making SQL statements on a CSV file? Are you importing the CSV file to a database first?

Comment: i am working in PHPSTORM and im just selecting from the csv file

Comment: @alon oak: please edit clarifications into the question, rather than as comments. The question should stand on its own, and be understandable without reading the comments.

Comment: I agree with @outis. The mention of the CSV file was a red herring, but the fact that you're using SQL Server was important and should be mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(A.albumName) AS totalAlbums , A.artistName FROM iTunes A
 ORDER BY totalAlbums DESC
```

Comment: not working :( , perhaps my PHP code isnt right? after the code i have                     $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
     $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
         echo $row['artistName'];

Comment: @alonoak Is it giving you an error? dump the row and result. var_dump($result)

Comment: no error, the page is simply not showing anything under the header where the sql is

Comment: @alonoak Did you try var_dumo?

Comment: I am sorry for the ignorance, I am not sure where to added the command

Comment: @alonoak Instead of `echo $row['artistName']` have `var_dump($row); var_dump($result);`

Comment: it wrote me: bool(false) bool(false)

Comment: @alonoak That's because sql query failed to execute. Try to run the sql directly to see the error. If you have Phpmyadmin use that.

Comment: dont think i'll be able to fix that, thanks for you time. ill just send an e-mail for the teacher for aid

Comment: @alonoak It As the last attempt try this: 
`SELECT COUNT(A.albumName) AS totalAlbums , A.artistName FROM iTunes A GROUP BY A.artistName
 ORDER BY totalAlbums DESC limit 1`

Comment: Same from befor, bool(false) bool(false), cheers mate

Comment: @alonoak Ok, I hope you'll figure it out. gl

Comment: I'm still confused: sqlsrv_query is PHP's function to query a Microsoft SQL Server connection. You say you have a CSV file. Are you sure your data is in a SQL Server? Can you show some more code, including the sqlsrv_connect command?

Comment: yes im connected to the sql server (and git) to my school's server and the command is    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $c);

Comment: @Parsa_Gholipour great success! apprently my server isnt working with  "limit" function changed it to : "SELECT TOP 1 COUNT..." and deleted the limit 1, thanks for the help!

Comment: @alonoak Yes, you are right, I didn't notice you are working on SQL server. I changed the answer(I hope it's correct) as it might help others too

Comment: @alonoak: the confusion in the comments and originally non-working answer (`LIMIT` isn't supported on SQL Server) shows the importance of putting relevant information (in this case, the RDBMS) in the question itself. You can also use tags for certain aspects (such as the relevant parts of the software environment). Also, please read and follow the guidelines in the [homework FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822).